# Swap odd and even numbers in array

Tags: java, recursion

I saw this code on this site. It uses a method to sort out an array with even numbers coming out in the front and odd numbers in the back of the array. I was wondering if you could do the same thing except make the odd numbers appear first and then the even numbers afterward? I tried but to no avail. I am new to coding in java and I wanted to test recursion.

```
public class Recurse {

//i=left 
//j=right
//first i tried to shift the whole thing
//have all even numbers pop to the front of array when even
public static int[] seperator(int[] arr1, int left, int right){
    int temp;
    if(left>=right)       //base case, return array
        return arr1; 
    else if(arr1[left]%2!=0 && arr1[right]%2==0){//if match, do the swap
        temp=arr1[left];
        arr1[left]=arr1[right];
        arr1[right]=temp;   
        return seperator(arr1, left+1, right-1);
    }
    else{
        if(arr1[right]%2!=0){//if right side is on odd #, then decrease index
            return seperator(arr1, left, right-1);
        }
        if(arr1[left]%2==0){//if left side is on even #, then increase index
            return seperator(arr1, left+1, right);
        }
    } 
    return arr1;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    //int index=0;
    int[] arry={70,13,48,19,24,5,7,10};

    int[] newarry=seperator(arry, 0, arry.length-1);
    System.out.print("The new sorted array is: ");
    for(int i=0; i<newarry.length;i++){
        System.out.print(newarry[i]+" ");
    } 
}
```

}

the output is this:

```
  The new sorted array is: 70 10 48 24 19 5 7 13
```

Comment: it would be good behaviour to disclose which site you saw it at, if there's no reason to hide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want the odd numbers to come first, replace any `%2!=0` with `%2==0` and any `%2==0` with `%2!=0` :

```
  public static int[] seperator(int[] arr1, int left, int right){
    int temp;
    if(left>=right)       
      return arr1; 
    else if(arr1[left]%2==0 && arr1[right]%2!=0){
      temp=arr1[left];
      arr1[left]=arr1[right];
      arr1[right]=temp;   
      return seperator(arr1, left+1, right-1);
    }
    else{
      if(arr1[right]%2==0){//if right side is on even #, then decrease index
        return seperator(arr1, left, right-1);
      }
      if(arr1[left]%2!=0){//if left side is on odd #, then increase index
        return seperator(arr1, left+1, right);
      }
    } 
    return arr1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out something like:

```
public static int[] seperator(int[] arr1, int left, int right) {
    int temp;
    if (left >= right) // base case, return array
        return arr1;
    else if (arr1[left] % 2 == 0 && arr1[right] % 2 != 0) {// if match, do the swap
        temp = arr1[left];
        arr1[left] = arr1[right];
        arr1[right] = temp;
        return seperator(arr1, left + 1, right - 1);
    } else {
        if (arr1[right] % 2 == 0) {// if right side is on odd #, then decrease index
            return seperator(arr1, left, right - 1);
        }
        if (arr1[left] % 2 != 0) {// if left side is on even #, then increase index
            return seperator(arr1, left + 1, right);
        }
    }
    return arr1;
}
Output:
The new sorted array is: 7 13 5 19 24 48 70 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 46, 50 };

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < a.length-1; j++) {
                if (a[j] % 2 != 0) {
                    int temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```